# From wich commit was a PR created?

Tags: git, commit, pull-request

I have a `feature` branch wich was created from the `main` branch.

**Question:** How do I know from which `main` commit `feature` was created? In this case the answer is 2.

```
main:      - 1 - 2 - 3 - 4 - 
feature:         \ - x - y - z
```

I indicate commits in `main` with numbers and in `feature` witch letters.

Comment: **tl;dr**: `git reflog show --no-abbrev featurebranch`

Answer (score 0):

if you use `git log` you can scroll through the commits until you see the one from main which you used to split off your `feature` branch.